# Generating multi CSS class names with Razor in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I need to generate multi CSS class names in a view using Razor, however Razor treats white space a bit tricky

```
<footer class=@HtmlHelpers.TruthyValueSelector(false,"footer","footer footer--no--border">

</footer>
```

My helper method:

```
public static string TruthyValueSelector(bool condition, string firstParameter, string secondParameter)
        {
            if (condition)
                return $"{firstParameter}";
            return $"{secondParameter}";
        }
```

when I inspect the element, the footer css class is: `class="footer" footer--no--border=""`

Of course, this is not going to work. My attempts in handling this situation cleanly with C# and Razor has not been successful. How can I take care of this in Razor?

Comment: Tip: Proper helper methods are extension methods with `(this HtmlHelper<T> html, ...` as the first parameter.

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior locally. What version of ASP.NET are you using? And are you targeting the .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Comment: Is the method `TruthyValueSelector` being invoked? Put a debug point to validate if the method is called.

Comment: You don't need to use interpolated strings either - just put `return firstParameter;` or `return secondParameter;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the ternary operator:

```
<footer class="@( someBooleanValue ? "footer" : "footer footer--no--border" )">

</footer>
```

This renders like this on my machine (when `someBooleanValue` is false):

```
<footer class="footer footer--no--border">

</footer>
```